# How to show list of records using @RemoteAction in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing `@RemoteAction` example in Salesforce. I have the following code, when I execute that I expect to see list of Accounts, also my query returning list of Accounts, but how we can show all those records using VF ?

**AccountRemoteActionController**

```
global class AccountRemoteActionController {
    public String accountName { get; set; }
    public static List<Account> accounts { get; set; }

    public AccountRemoteActionController(){}

    @RemoteAction
    global static List<Account> getAccount(String accountName){
        String updatedAccName = '%'+accountName+'%';
        accounts = [select id, name, phone, type, numberofemployees from Account where name LIKE :updatedAccName];
        System.debug('Account Size : '+accounts.size());
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

**AccountRemoteActionControllerVFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoteActionController">
    <script>
        function getAccountJS(){
            var accountNameJS = document.getElementById('accName').value; 
            AccountRemoteActionController.getAccount(accountNameJS, 
                function(result, event){
                    if(event.status){
                        for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
                            document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.thePageBlockSection.theFirstItem.accId}").innerHTML = result[i].Id;
                            document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.thePageBlockSection.theSecondItem.accNam}").innerHTML = result[i].Name;
                            document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.thePageBlockSection.theThirdItem.accPhone}").innerHTML = result[i].Phone;
                        }
                    }else if(event.type === 'exception'){
                        document.getElementById("errors-js").innerHTML = event.message;
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("errors-js").innerHTML = 'No Records Found..';
                    }
                },{escape : true});
        }
    </script>
    Account Name : <input id="accName" type="text" />
    <button onclick="getAccountJS()">Get Account</button>
    <div id="errors-js"></div>

    <apex:pageBlock id="theBLock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="thePageBlockSection" columns="4">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theFirstItem">
                <apex:outputText id="accId"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSecondItem" >
                <apex:outputText id="accNam" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theThirdItem" >
                <apex:outputText id="accPhone" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

**Here I want to see all accounts which SOQL query returns.**

Here is the result of SOQL:

[image]

Comment: You'd need to construct your own HTML table in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the good way of implementing the solution:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountRemoteActionController">
    <style>
        table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
    </style>
    <script>
        function getAccountJS(){
            var accountNameJS = document.getElementById('accName').value; 
            AccountRemoteActionController.getAccount(accountNameJS, 
                function(result, event){
                    var root, table, a, caption, bold, text, tr, th, td;
                    table = document.createElement("table");
                    table.className="gridtable";

                    caption = document.createElement("caption");
                    bold = document.createElement("b");
                    text = document.createTextNode("Account Details");
                    bold.appendChild(text);
                    caption.appendChild(bold);
                    table.appendChild(caption);

                    tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    th = document.createElement("th");
                    text = document.createTextNode("Name");
                    th.appendChild(text);
                    tr.appendChild(th);

                    th = document.createElement("th");
                    text = document.createTextNode("Phone");
                    th.appendChild(text);
                    tr.appendChild(th);

                    th = document.createElement("th");
                    text = document.createTextNode("Type");
                    th.appendChild(text);
                    tr.appendChild(th);

                    table.appendChild(tr);

                    if(event.status && event.result){
                        event.result.length = Object.keys(event.result).length;
                        Array.prototype.forEach.call(event.result, function(row) {
                            tr = document.createElement("tr");
                            td = document.createElement("td");
                            a = document.createElement("a");
                            a.href = "/"+row.Id;
                            text = document.createTextNode(row.Name);
                            a.appendChild(text);
                            td.appendChild(a);
                            tr.appendChild(td);

                            td = document.createElement("td");
                            text = document.createTextNode(row.Phone || "");
                            td.appendChild(text);
                            tr.appendChild(td);

                            td = document.createElement("td");
                            text = document.createTextNode(row.Type || "");

                            td.appendChild(text);
                            tr.appendChild(td);

                            table.appendChild(tr);
                        });
                    }

                    root = document.getElementById("accDetails");
                    while(root.firstChild) {
                        root.removeChild(root.firstChild);
                    }
                    root.appendChild(table);
                },{escape : true});
        }
    </script>
    Account Name : <input id="accName" type="text" />
    <button onclick="getAccountJS()">Get Account</button>
    <div id="errors-js"></div>
    <div id="accDetails"></div>

    <apex:pageBlock id="theBLock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="thePageBlockSection" columns="4">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theFirstItem">
                <apex:outputText id="accId"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSecondItem" >
                <apex:outputText id="accNam" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theThirdItem" >
                <apex:outputText id="accPhone" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the output:
Reference for CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r5v7q1js/

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I am answering on the basis that you are getting a list of accounts using the remote action. Now, to show a list of accounts you need to develop a table on the UI. Let me give you a basic example with simple table.

Have a `<div/>` to show your data in page.

```
<div id="resultsPanel"></div>
```

Now in your success callback function, we will be creating the table dynamically using JavaScript from the retrieved list of accounts.

```
function(result, event){
    if(event.status){
        var resultPanel = document.getElementById('resultsPanel');

        var tableHTML = '<table><tr><th>Acc Id</th><th>Acc Name</th><th>Acc Phone</th></tr>';
        for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
            tableHTML += '<tr>';
            tableHTML += '<td>'+result[i].Id+'</td>';
            tableHTML += '<td>'+result[i].Name+'</td>';
            tableHTML += '<td>'+result[i].Phone!='undefined'?result[i].Phone:''+'</td>';
            tableHTML += '</tr>';
        }
        tableHTML += '</table>';
        resultPanel.innerHTML = tableHTML;
    }else if(event.type === 'exception'){
        document.getElementById("errors-js").innerHTML = event.message;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errors-js").innerHTML = 'No Records Found..';
    }
}
```